# HTML Table creation - when an event as occured

Tags: html-table

I have created an HTML Table. I need to display this table only when a button is clicked. Could some one suggest how to achieve this?

Regards
Giri

Comment: using what? JavaScript or asp.net ?

Comment: What language are you using? Php? JavaScript? Html?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery and attached an handler.
for example
in html:

```
<a class="button-link" href="javascript:void(0);">link</a>
<table class='hidden-table'>
<tr>
<th>id</th><th>name</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td><td>Mr Awesome</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

in css:

```
.hidden-table{
   display:none;
}
```

in js/jquery

```
$('.button-link').on('click',function(){
    $('.hidden-table').show()
})
```

use the css to hide the table first and then upon clicking on the link it will show the table.

Comment: Please accept as an answer so that if someone else look out for the same question they will know that this question has an answer. Thanks and have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Jquery, from here http://jquery.com/download/ .

After installing, you could use the following syntax:

```
$('#idofthebutton').click(function(){


$('#idofthetable').toggle();


});
```